# Invalid repository selection. Creating a new connection will require 'All repositories' access to automate the repository creation process

Tags: xm-cloud

I was doing the XM Cloud setup, and while importing a GitHub repository, I got the below error. Let me know if anyone else got the same issue and what the fix was.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering here so quickly, but I got the fix; basically, while doing the import, we have to choose all repositories and can't choose a selected repository. My problem was resolved after importing the entire repository. Thank you all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After selecting *continue with Github*, you will need to select an existing Github connection or create a new GitHub connection but make sure to **provide All repository access**.

[image]

[image]